# Transparent PDF compressor?

Tags: pdf, file-compression

I would like to be able to use a PDF compressor where I know exactly what it's doing and can control exactly what it's doing.   It doesn't need to be the fanciest or have absolutely the most extreme compression ratio, as long as it meets those requirements.  Most PDF compressors are opaque black boxes, and I have no real idea what they're doing and/or they're doing things that I don't like (such as deleting the "/Info" element), with no control.  Much thanks for any suggestions or help...

Comment: Does it need to be a ready to use application? If not, I've found this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614350/compress-pdf-with-large-images-via-java You didn't either mention your target platform so here is a ready application for Windows: https://github.com/pgodwin/PdfShrinker Or simple python script: https://github.com/theeko74/pdfc // So please add to your question: target platform, does it need to be free software, etc.

Comment: You can try `cpdf -squeeze in.pdf -o out.pdf`. It is, indeed, a black box. But a rather safe one: it won't delete anything. It just re-arranges existing structure, merging identical objects and fixing compression.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify a platform, but I'm agnostic between submitting a PDF file to be compressed through a web-page, or running a Windows 10 executable.  I also have access to the NetBSD command line (but not X windows). 
I downloaded CPDF, and it "squeezed" my test PDF file by almost 10%.  However, the advantage is much less when the squeezed file is then included in a ZIP-compressed archive.  CPDF also changed the PDF version number of the file from 1.2 to 1.5, and eliminated the plain-text Xref table near the end, so that the file can no longer be handled by older PDF-viewing programs.